# Object == Object2 when stored in List<T> but not when object in IEnumerable<T> - WHY?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, list, ienumerable

**Using ASP MVC5 and EF6.**

I had a curious case the other day when I was looking to have different behaviour when a foreach-loop got to the last element.
The loop wouldn't enter if-condition comparing the object with the result from .Last()-method on the collection.

The collection I was iterating over was something like:

```
public class CollectionClass{
    IEnumerable<TestClass1> CollectionA
    IEnumerable<TestClass2> CollectionB
}
```

My code was something like:

```
DbContext db = new DbContext(); //just for illustration, not actual code

CollectionClass cc = new CollectionClass {
   CollectionA = db.TestClasses1,
   CollectionB = db.TestClasses2
};

//(TestClasses1 and TestClasses2 are DbSet<T> properties of my DbContext. 

foreach(TestClass1 tc1 in cc.CollectionA)
{
  if (tc1 == cc.CollectionA.Last()){    //<---NEVER enters in here!!
    //doStuff
  }
  else{
    //doOtherStuff
  }
}
```

With the code above, the loop never entered into the if-condition, even for the last element, which one would expect.
But when changed my *CollectionClass* to:

```
public class CollectionClass{
    List<TestClass1> CollectionA
    List<TestClass2> CollectionB
}
```

and instantiated the *CollectionClass*-object like this:

```
CollectionClass cc = new CollectionClass {
   CollectionA = db.TestClasses1.ToList(), 
   CollectionB = db.TestClasses2.ToList()
}; //Added .ToList()
```

the loop entered into the first if-condition at the last iteration as I expected.

Why this difference? Why did the equals-operator (==) evaluate to TRUE when the object had been stored in a List and FALSE when the object was stored in an IEnumerable?
I know that IEnumerable is an interface -- is that what makes the difference?

I even did an explicit test in the sorts of:

```
var obj1 = cc.CollectionA.Last();
var obj2 cc.CollectionA.Last();
bool result = obj1 == obj2; //result = FALSE
```

and the result was FALSE.

Comment: Your code wouldn't even compile. You're trying to iterate over `cc`, which doesn't implement `IEnumerable` or have a `GetEnumerator` method. It would be a lot easier to help you if you'd post a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Keen eyes! Fixed the code example to iterate over cc.CollectionA

Comment: Well that's still not a short but complete example...

Comment: and what `cc.Last()` does?

Comment: Sorry, I'm really tired so I missed a few obvious errors in the code example. It was supposed to be cc.CollectionA.Last();
Thanks Peri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because in first example you get two objects from database. First from iteration and second from call to `Last()`.

In second example all objects are created at the time you assign collections to `CollectionA` and `CollectionB` (you call `ToList()`).

Comment: I believe this must be the answer. I even tested comparing the items explicitly by doing: var obj1 = cc.CollectionA.First(); var obj2 cc.CollectionA.First(); bool result = obj1 == obj2; and the result was FALSE.

Comment: You can be sure if you open SQL Profiler or Entity Framework Profiler. You will see different database calls if I'm right - and I am ;)

Comment: If this last snippet returns true for `List` collections then you know what is happening and you don't have to run any profilers.

Answer (score -1):

It is because you are not allowed to use `Last` and `LastOrDefault` on `DbSet` objects. Instead you should  use `OrderByDescending(t=>t.ID).First()`